# How to bind IsSelected ListboxItem property in a windows phone application?

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In WPF I used to do this:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This is not working on a Windows Phone 8 application as I'm getting an expection saying that the property is readonly.

How should I do this simple task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came through this issue before, it seems like binding through property setters isn't supported. However, there is a workaround. You can subclass ListBox and override `PrepareContainerForItemOverride`. This method is invoked on each item that needs to be added to the list which makes it a perfect place to set your binding there. You won't need to anything special to your Xaml in that case

```cs
public class ListBoxEx : ListBox {
  protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(System.Windows.DependencyObject element, object item) {
    base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    ((ListBoxItem)element).IsSelected = ((MyModel)item).IsSelected;
  }
}
```

```xml
<local:ListBoxEx>
  <local:ListBoxEx.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <!-- Bind your properties as you would normally do -->
    </DataTemplate>
  </local:ListBoxEx.ItemTemplate>
</local:ListBoxEx>
```

Comment: Thanks. How did you subclass the ListBox, when I do I get different exceptions ... which is weird.

Comment: What exception are you getting? I subclassed it by adding only the above code.